# jsoup - how to obtain links from a text of an article in Wikipedia

Tags: java, jsoup, html-parsing

I have just started to explore Jsoup and faced the following problem: when I'm trying to extract links from `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge` that belong only to the English version of Wikipedia everything works correctly.

```
    Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge").timeout(6000).get();
    Elements linksOnPage = document.select( "a[href^=\"/wiki/\"]");

    for (Element link : linksOnPage) {
        System.out.println("link : " + link.attr("abs:href"));
    }  
}
```

However I'm also getting the links that do not belong to the text of the current article such as:

```
    link : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page
    link : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal:Contents
    link : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal:Featured_content
    link : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal:Current_events
    link : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random
    link : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Contents
    link : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:About
    link : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Community_portal
```

What is the proper way to get only the links from the text leading to other Wikipedia articles with Jsoup?

Comment: https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

Comment: @matoni thanks. I found that the links that I do not need are located in the `div id="mw-panel"`. So I've edited the selector for the links according to the jsoup cookbook like that: `Elements linksOnPage = document.select( "a[href^=\"/wiki/\"], div:not(.mw-panel)");`. But I'm still getting the unneeded links from the Wikipedia side panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> links that I do not need are located in the div id="mw-panel"

Therefore the correct selector would be:

```
div:not(#mw-panel) a[href^="/wiki/"]
```

Which will select `<a>` elements that:

- are not inside a `<div>` element with `mw-panel` ID
- and their `href` attribute starts with `"/wiki/"`.

EDIT:

> I need only the links from an article without links from the side panels and without any links such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:BookSources/978-1-4200‌​-5940-3 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:BookSources/1-58450-46‌​0-9

Then you may try:

```
#bodyContent a[href^="/wiki/"]
```

This will parse links that:

- are inside the article (`<div>` with ID of `bodyContent`)
- their `href` attribute starts with `"/wiki/"`

`div#bodyContent` does not have `"/wiki/...Special:..."` links. (If you want to exclude links with some other word, append this to the end of the above selector without any space or separator: `:not([href*="something"])`)

You can also try to combine selectors to achieve the best pattern based on my tryings above and by [reading about Jsoup selectors](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax).

Example code:

```
String url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge";
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(6000).get();
Elements links = document.select("#bodyContent a[href^=\"/wiki/\"]");
for (Element e : links) {
    System.out.println(e.attr("href"));
}
System.out.println("Links found: " + links.size());
```

This prints out following:

```
/wiki/Knowledge_(disambiguation)
/wiki/Fact
/wiki/Information
...
/wiki/Category:Articles_with_unsourced_statements_from_September_2007
/wiki/Category:Articles_with_unsourced_statements_from_May_2009
/wiki/Category:Wikipedia_articles_with_GND_identifiers
Links found: 826
```

Comment: thank you @juzraai but it did not help. I need only the links from an article without links from the side panels and without any links such as: `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:BookSources/978-1-4200-5940-3`
`https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:BookSources/1-58450-460-9`

Comment: Please see my edited answer, I added another potential solution.

Comment: When I try to use your suggestions it returns just one url of the initial page. For some reason not only hrefs with `"Special:"` get elimineted. I should probably try regex.

Comment: thank you for help, @juzraai! It finally got working)